# How Use WebGrid In orchard

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, webgrid

i am try to use WebGrid class in Orchard .BUt it not Accessible on .csHtml  page.i have added System.Wed.Helpers nameSpace  on .csHtml page But it is not working.

please  help me How we Done this in orchard

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MVC with Orchard. Have a look here; http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/251384